# EntityNotFoundException performing POST method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I develop app managing surveys. Performing POST method to create new Survey using @RestController I get an error

```
2020-02-19 18:10:34.257 ERROR 8648 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find pl.wsisiz.asp.domain.OptionGroup with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find pl.wsisiz.asp.domain.OptionGroup with id 1] with root cause
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find pl.wsisiz.asp.domain.OptionGroup with id 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at ...
.....
```

Since error is `unable to find optionGroupId` I think that the issue may be related with relationship between Question and OptionGroup. OptionGroups can be used in many Questions but Question has always 1 or no OptionGroup.

Model - Question.java

```
package pl.wsisiz.asp.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Integer questionId;

    //other fields
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "option_group_id")
    // @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) //with this line there is no error
                                                // and optionGroup is always null 
    private OptionGroup optionGroup;
}
```

Model - OptionGroup.java

```
package pl.wsisiz.asp.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "option_groups")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OptionGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "option_group_id")
    private Integer optionGroupId;

    //other fields
    // ...


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "optionGroup", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Question> questions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}
```

While performing POST method, Controller uses `addSurvey(@RequestBody SurveyTemplate surveyTemplate)`. surveyTemplate is saved by `save()` method from JpaRepository.

Calling this POST method I put to body JSON which I received using GET method (after that I removed database content). JSON which I put to body looks like this:

```
{
        "surveyTemplateId": 1,
        "surveyName": "Example survey",
        "instructions": null,
        "otherInfo": null,
        "surveySections": [
            {
                "surveySectionId": 1,
                "sectionName": "Metric",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "questionId": 1,
                        "questionName": "Age:",
                        "answerRequired": true,
                        "inputType": "CHOICE",
                        "subquestions": [],
                        "optionGroup": {
                            "optionGroupId": 1,
                            "optionGroupName": "age20-25+",
                            "optionChoices": [
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 1,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "less than 20"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 2,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "20"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 3,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "21"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 4,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "22"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 5,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "23"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 6,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "24"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionChoiceId": 7,
                                    "optionChoiceName": "more than 25"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**EDIT:**

When I replaced many-to-one relationship(marked in the diagram) with many-to-mamy, everything works properly. You can see the whole ERD from before this change. However, I don't actually know why it doesn't work with many-to-one and if there is a way to make it with many-to-one relationship.

[image: ERD]

Comment: Is your entity listed in the persistence.xml? If you have multiple persistence units, are you using the correct entity manager and schema?

Comment: @Stefan I use Spring boot, so I don't use persistence.xml